# Newsletter Unsubscribe link

Tags: magento2, newsletter

In my store (Magento 2.4.1) I have the option for customers to subscribe to our Newsletter using Magento native newsletter module.

I use a thrid party service to send newsletter emails and I need to include the unsubcribe link in this emails. How can I get the unsubscribe link? is this a fixed link or does it change from customer to customer?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With native Magento Newsletter extension you need to pass 2 arguments to unsubscribe action (`id` and `code`) and it's made by security reason to prevent unsubscribe any customer by email.

You can find source data in `newsletter_subscriber` table

You can share `subscriber_id` and `subscriber_confirm_code` into your 3rd party extension and generate a link using this 2 fields or use some another identifier(s) and create custom controller for unsubscribe

If you want to create your custom action you can find unsubscribe logic in `\Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\Unsubscribe`

Native URL is `/newsletter/subscriber/unsubscribe/id/{$ID}/code/{$CODE}`

Comment: thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

please try this in your template :

```
<a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">Unsubscribe</a>
```